# Is there a better way to create a Jar file than with BlueJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, bluej

I have a program I want to make into a jar file, so I did that with bluej, and the jar's size is very large, like 400MB. Not even Windows is that big.

One of my friends told me that I can create it with Eclipse, and it would be smaller. But I don't know if that's actually practical, since there's not that much info on it when you Google it (thus conclusion, there's a better way to do it).

Currently I'm trying trying that though, maybe I'll get it to work.  But in the meantime if there is a better way, would someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that jar files are just zip files with a cherry on top.

Comment: .....O.o oh snap... then im busy with the wrong thing... I need an executible jar.... Dammmmmmit! there goes 2hours of my life....

Comment: Do you have somebody more experienced nearby?  It might be a trivial thing.

Comment: I figured it out with the help of you all, so thanx allot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command-line `jar` tool is very easy to use, and you can control exactly what goes into your file. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) is the page in the Java Tutorial describing the basics of using it. It's embedded in a larger tutorial about the many additional subtleties you might need to consider.

Comment: Thank you. Im going through evertything there,  and im trying it now. Dont know if im doing it right though, as my command promt is telling me that it does not recognize 'jar'....

Comment: You need to have your (JDK)/bin directory on your PATH environment variable. This is the same thing you need to do to be able to run `javac`, the Java compiler, on the command line, and it's a great first step away from the training wheels of Bluejay. Try these instructions, as appropriate for your OS: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/how-to-create-java-program#SettingJavahomeAndPath

Comment: ahh brilliant, i see. Oky so i could declare my variables, and they work in command promt. So now ive created a simple hello program. (just says hello) in the file is. Hello.class Hello.ctxt Hello.java and my Hello.mf I followed the instructions here [link](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/85application/jar/jar.html) and it creates the jar, but when i try to run it.. it trows an error? Failed to load main-class Manifest attribute from Hello.jar. Any idea? (thank you for everything so far)

Comment: ah i have it, you have to have a blank line at the end of your manifest txtfile. 
Thanx alot! YOU REaaaaaaly helped me!!!

Comment: Yeah, you either have no MANIFEST.mf file or if you have one your Main-Class: is not defined there.

Comment: Great news. Good luck in the future!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds huge and un-proportional, unless you have many big files except of the code, but you can use the [JDK tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/) - where [**jar**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) is the tool you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does make it very easy.  You can just right click the file, choose 'export', choose 'create a runnable JAR', and decide where it should go.  Cake, no lies.

Comment: haha thanx, but then i have to strule getting a 500mb bluej program to work on eclips... and you have any idea what pain in the ass that is??! (well so far =P )

Answer (score 0):

I use ant to do my build and create the jar file and war file for my web app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JCreator or Netbeans. It may help you to reduce the size.